# Catchin a text in Linux-Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash

How can I catch the text in specific table which is seen with another code on cli?
Or how to catch the text in same design another way?

That is sample table

```
***pool-name             subnet               mask-len  vr-id
--------------------  -------------------  --------  -----
dataoam               10.254.140.160       27        0***
```

and I need a `dataoam`

Comment: I suggest you tell us about that "another code on cli", o that we can play around with it...

Comment: cli can get clear on "Command-line interface"

Comment: I do know what you mean by "cli". But we cannot help without seeing the actual output you get. You certainly do not get a "table" as a cli call output. That is why I asked you to post the command, so that we can analyse the output.

Comment: networking show all where pool-end < 10.254.140.195 and pool-start > 10.254.140.160

Comment: that is my code which is shows the table

Comment: and i need a subnet name and that is dataoam

Comment: I am not aware of a utility called `networking` that accepts such an argument list

Comment: Are you running a certain command like "$dump_table_info" and seeing the output table? Are you looking to see an entire row containing "dataoam" filtered out of the output?

Comment: ı am running the "networking show all where pool-end < 10.254.140.195 and pool-start > 10.254.140.160" and ı see that table

Comment: if ı run networking pool show all.ı can see al the pools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit unclear which command you are using, ("networking show all..." does not name an actual command on my system), but assuming a given command yields your output, you can use tail and awk:

```
<your command> | tail -n +3 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Example:

```
jvc@BlueBuilder:~$ cat out.txt
***pool-name             subnet               mask-len  vr-id
--------------------  -------------------  --------  -----
dataoam               10.254.140.160       27        0***
```

and

```
jvc@BlueBuilder:~$ cat out.txt | tail -n +3 | awk '{print $1}'
dataoam
```

Comment: I try the awk and ı am trying your code now but that system isnt accept the pipe line.ı dont know why.I am learnig a bash since 3 week and that is big problem for me

Comment: Show your output.

Comment: networking pool show all where pool-start > 10.254.140.141 and pool-end < 10.25
4.140.195 | tail -n +3 | awk '{print $1}'  
                 ^
...................................% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Comment: Ok - what I mean was, show the *complete* output from your terminal (including your prompt and new line) and use the Code Sample formatting to get fixed-width character formatting. You may have to do this in your question (edit it). The formatting of your output is relevant!

Comment: It just dawns on me... it might be the pipe character you get wrong. Try copy-paste my command instead of typing it.